# Difference between full hints

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below join

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table1   t1
    JOIN table2   t2 ON t2.col = t1.col
```

What would be the difference between the below?

```
SELECT /*+ FULL(t1) */
    *
FROM
    table1   t1
    JOIN table2   t2 ON t2.col = t1.col
```

```
SELECT /*+ FULL(t1) FULL(t2) */
    *
FROM
    table1   t1
    JOIN table2   t2 ON t2.col = t1.col
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first query, you are only hinting that Oracle should perform a full scan of table `T1`.  If `T1` is small and `T2` is large, the optimizer may still decide to access `T2` via an index within a nested loop join.

In the second query, you are hinting that Oracle should perform a full scan of BOTH tables.  So, even if `T1` is small and `T2` is large, your hint will likely cause the optimizer to full scan both tables and join them using a hash join.

... and, that would be slower, probably.  This is an example of what you usually DON'T want to do with hints -- you don't want to tell the optimizer how to do it's job.  If you are not getting what you want out of the optimizer, it's better to start with hints that give the optimizer more information (e.g., `/*+ CARDINALITY (nnnn) */` or `/*+ DYNAMIC_SAMPLING(4) */`)

Comment: The optimizer won't decide purely based on the size of the tables, but with how selective the join filter is and how clustered together the rows it expects to find will be (assuming there is even an index that makes sense). Arguably, it is more likely that two full scans and a hash join is going to be the fastest plan as there's no other filters besides the join - we don't know how good of a filter the join condition is though. It is not better to use the `CARDINALITY` hint, it is not documented and can lead to buggy behaviour

Comment: The example was to illustrate how the hints can constrain the optimizer.  It was not intended to be a comprehensive description of how it works in each case.  Small T1, big T2 is a common case for a nested loop join with index.  Yes, there are caveats.

Regarding `CARDINALITY` it was deemed relatively 'safe" by Tom Kyte (https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2233040800346569775) and that's good enough for me.  I would not use it to override cardinality that the optimizer can get through stats or extended stats.  But it's good for TABLE() clauses etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, Tom had just not been burned by the bugs he mentions it being safe from. I have personally hit wrong results bugs when using the `cardinality` hint, it needs to be considered.